# Can I delete a downvoted question that I answered myself (where nobody else has answered it)?

Tags: support, vote-to-delete, self-answer

Recently I asked a question on Ask Ubuntu. I did not get any answer. Then after searching I found the solution and wrote it as an answer. I got one upvote for the answer and 0 for the question:

[how to make symbolic links of the files from folder to folder](https://askubuntu.com/q/1197558/739431)

After that, someone downvoted both my question and answer. This is causing me to think that my question is not good and this community is not encouraging this kind of question.

So can I delete the question for which I only have written an answer?

Comment: That's a good question. I would recommend not deleting it

Comment: Ok, thank you for editing and your action on the link.. @Zanna

Comment: Some downvotes are cast blindly just like upvotes. But like [terdon said](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/18939/816190), don't immediately jump to deletion. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, if you got one downvote, all that means is that one person felt the question should be downvoted. It doesn't in any way imply anything at all about "the community". It only shows the opinion of one, single, non-representative user.

That said, I admit your answer is really kind of bad in that it has a few dangerously bad practices in there. You are [parsing ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and you are using [shell variables unquoted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/22222). So I can understand the downvote.

But when you get a downvote, you should just think of ways of improving your post, don't immediately jump to deletion. Yes, you can delete it, if you like, but it would be much better to improve it instead. I have posted a safer solution,

Comment: This is exactly what I would say in response as well to the question.  Don't immediately jump to 'deletion' as your solution to a single downvote, just work to improve the post.